# Find all consecutive letter sequences (character grams) in a word, from length 1 to the length of the word

Tags: python

This works:

```
s = 'beach'
lst = []

for c in range(len(s) + 1):
    lst.append(list(zip(*[s[i:] for i in range(c)])))

lst2 = [''.join(j) for i in lst for j in i]
print(lst2)

# output
# ['b', 'e', 'a', 'c', 'h', 'be', 'ea', 'ac', 'ch', 'bea', 'eac', 'ach', 'beac', 'each', 'beach']
```

But is there a cleaner, more elegant and more Pythonic way to achieve the same result?

Comment: This type of post should be on [code-review].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Make a function out of it. That way you emphasize input and output, and also have a default place to put your explanations.

Second: Try to outline the logic you're trying to apply by using names that implicate the variables content or use.

Third: Try to make only one logical step per line, or comment what you've done.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
def parts(word):
""" Returns a list of all substrings of a string"""
    combs = combinations_with_replacement(range(len(word)),2)
    return [word[x[0]:x[1]+1] for x in combs]
```